# Find letters from an a.txt file in a b.txt file C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asmx

at this moment I am uploading 2 txt files. In the file 'A' I have a list of letters and in the file 'B' I have a couple of words, I am reading the 2 files, and I add them in a list. The goal is according to the letters of the 'A' file to find if words can be formed from the 'B' file. Example:

Contents of the 'A' file:
E
B
Y
O
P
D
R
B
A

Contents of the 'B' file:
POBEDA,
COBALT

In this case the word found in POBEDA

I'm using a web service to perform the process

This is the Web Service:

```
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string Leerdata()
        {


            var path = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\thoma\source\repos\NewShoreApp\NewShoreApp\Data\", "*.txt");

            List<string> list = path.ToList();
            Parallel.ForEach(path, current =>
            {
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(current);

                list.AddRange(lines.ToList());
            });


            return String.Join(",", list);


            }

    }
```

This is the controller:

```
namespace NewShoreApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
                    {
                        if (file != null)
                        {
                            var ServerPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Data"), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));

                            file.SaveAs(ServerPath);
                        }
                    }                    
                    ViewBag.FileStatus = "File uploaded successfully.";
                }

                catch (Exception)   
                {

                    ViewBag.FileStatus = "Error while file uploading.";
                } 

            }
            return View("Index");
        }


    }
}
```

This is the model:

```
namespace NewShoreApp.Models
{
    public class Data
    {
        // 
        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        [Display(Name = "Upload File")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose file to upload.")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase[] files { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @madreflection Check if the letters you give me can I do the word

Comment: @Michael Randall Thanks for the recommendation

Comment: The key is to break this down in to two separate tasks, Reading all text from a text file, and comparing 2 strings for characters.`File.ReadAllText` will get you the first... (I revamped this comment because of the massive typos)

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple algorithm fro your problem.

(You can improve this algorithm, this algorithm is just for your reference)

Matching process between File "A" and "B" should be done like below :

1. Read a word from File "B"
2. Split that word into character array
3. Compare that character array's each elements with File "A"'s all character

   - if all characters are found in File "A" and 
     in character array, no any other character left to match(Not found in "A" file) 
     then It will be taken as "Not found"
   - if all characters are found in "A" File and in character array, 
     no other character left to match then It will be taken as "Found"
4. Get Next word from File "B"

   - If there is next word in File "B" then repeat step 2 & 3
   - If there is no next word in File "B" then you have finished 
     matching process between File "A" & "B". So terminate this process.

Comment: I'd use the following approach: read characters from file A, adding them to a dictionary (using the chars as keys, and either ``true`` or the number of occurrences as values, depending on requirements). Then read words from file B, and for each word, check if each letter is in the dictionary (and if required, whether you have used up all occurrences in the dictionary already or not); if the check is positive for each letter, the word can be formed, otherwise it cannot be formed. Once you have this functionality, wrapping it in a web service is probably easy.